# tf.while_loop only makes only one loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

After days of trying to apply a `tf.while_loop`, I still fail to understand how it works (or rather why it does not). The documentations and various questions here on StackOverflow haven't helped so far.

The main idea is to train the different columns of a tensor `trueY` separately using a `while_loop`. The problem is that when I trace this code, I see that the `while_loop` gets called only once.

I'd like to dynamically assign names to variables created in the `while_loop` so as to be able to access them outside the `while_loop` after they have been created (thus the "gen_name" function trying to dynamically generate names for the dense layers created in each loop), and make `tf.while_loop` run n times this way.

Here is a sample of my code with the issue (not the full code and modified to demonstrate this problem)

```
...................
config['dim_y'] = 10
Xl = tf.placeholder( self.dtype, shape=(batchsize, config['dim_x']) )
Yl = tf.placeholder( self.dtype, shape=(batchsize, config['dim_y']) )
Gl = tf.placeholder( self.dtype, shape=(batchsize, config['dim_g']) )
costl, cost_m, self.cost_b = self.__cost( Xl, Yl, Gl, False )

def __eval_cost( self, A, X, Y, G, reuse ):
    AGXY = tf.concat( [A, G, X, Y], -1 )
        Z, mu_phi3, ls_phi3 = build_nn( AGXY, ....,  reuse )

    _cost = -tf.reduce_sum( ls_phi3, -1 )
    _cost += .5 * tf.reduce_sum( tf.pow( mu_phi3, 2 ), -1 )
    _cost += .5 * tf.reduce_sum( tf.exp( 2*ls_phi3 ), -1 )
    return _cost



def __cost( self, trueX, trueY, trueG, reuse ):
    ........
    columns = tf.unstack(trueY, axis=-1)
    AGX = tf.concat( [ AX, G ], -1 )
    pre_Y  = self.build_nn( AGX, ....., reuse )
    index_loop = (tf.constant(0), _cost, _cost_bl)

    def condition(index, _cost, _cost_supervised_bi_label):
        return tf.less(index, self.config['dim_y'])


    def bodylabeled(index, _cost, _cost_bl):
        def gen_name(var_name):
            # split eg 'cost/while/strided_slice_5:0' => '5'
            # split eg 'cost/while/strided_slice:0' => 'slice'
            iter = var_name.split('/')[-1].split(':')[0].split('_')[-1]
            if iter == "slice":
                return '0phi2y'
            else:
                return '{}phi2y'.format(int(iter) % self.config['dim_y'])

        y_i = tf.gather(columns, index)
        y = tf.expand_dims( tf.one_hot(tf.to_int32(y_i, name='ToInt32'), depth, dtype=self.dtype ), 0 )
        Y = tf.tile( y, [self.config['L'],1,1] )
        c = tf.constant(0, name='test')
        log_pred_Y = tf.layers.dense( pre_Y, 2, name=gen_name(iter[index].name), reuse=reuse )
        log_pred_Y = log_pred_Y - tf.reduce_logsumexp( log_pred_Y, -1, keep_dims=True )

        _cost += self.__eval_cost_given_axgy( A, X, Y, G, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE )
        _cost_bl += -tf.reduce_sum( tf.multiply( Y, log_pred_Y ), -1 )
        return tf.add(index, 1), _cost, _cost_supervised_bi_label

    _cost, _bl = tf.while_loop(condition, bodylabeled, index_loop, parallel_iterations=1, shape_invariants=(index_loop[0].get_shape(), tf.TensorShape([None, 100]), tf.TensorShape([None, 100])))[1:]

op = costl + cost_m + cost_b
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    for batchl in batches:
       sess.run( op,
                feed_dict={Xl:Xl[batchl,:],
                         Yl:Yl[batchl,:].toarray(),
                         Gl:Gl[batchl,:].toarray(),
                         is_training:True } )

for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node:
    print(n.name)
```

Comment: print out or debug the actual condition values.  The most likely reason is something isn't the value you expect

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond, but the condition value is the "index"  which is passed a tf.constant(0) in the index_loop tuple and then increased by 1 in each loop. I don't see how it would suddenly jump to 10 or more after a loop to make the loop stop.

Comment: 0 is technically false?  Try going from 1 to 11 instead?